# deleting cookies and user redirection with next.js 13 does not work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies, routes, middleware

I'm creating a course platform, where a user, when registering on the application, receives a token that is stored in cookies, after 24 hours the token expires, and I want to delete the cookie, and redirect the user to the /login page, but I don't understand, request.cookie even says it deletes it, but it doesn't delete it from the browser, I used response.cookie.delete(), and it worked and I deleted it from the browser, but I have to give a return response for the deletion to work, because in the javascript I can't use anything below the return, I don't know how to redirect the user, and the return is read correctly and deletes the cookie and redirects him to log in again, I'm using middleware so I don't repeat code in all private routes, code below:

```
src/middleware.ts

import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = request.cookies.get("token")?.value!
  const res = NextResponse.next()

  const response = await fetch(`${request.nextUrl.origin}/api/verifycookie`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      cookies: cookie
    }
  })
  const data = await response.json()

  if(data.ExpiredToken){
    res.cookies.delete("token")
    return res
  }else if(data.error){
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signIn", request.url))
  }
}
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/home", "/cart", "/contact", "/exploreCourses", "/plains"]
}
```

code of the route verifyCookie below:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest){
    const cookieValue = request.headers.get("cookies")
    const url = process.env.URL

    const response = await fetch(`${url}/verifyExpToken`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${cookieValue}`
        }
    })
    const data = await response.json()

    if(data.error == "Token Expirado"){
        return NextResponse.json({ExpiredToken: "Token Expirado"}, {status: 403})
    }else if(data.error){
        return NextResponse.json({error: data.error}, {status: 401})
    }

    return NextResponse.json({success: "Token válido"}, {status: 200})
}
```

My question is, how can I actually delete the cookie, and redirect the user to /login? I tried different ways, and I couldn't

I've already tried to delete the cookies using request.cookies.delete, I expected it to delete them completely, both from the request and from the browser, but it doesn't delete them from the browser, and remains in devtools in the application tab, I tried creating a separate function with return NextResponse .redirect, and call the function outside, as there are two returns in different scope, and it didn't work either. But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, I used the library precisely for next.js, cookies-next, it serves the basic concepts of next js, it works in both client and server components, middleware, routehandler, server actions, etc.. ., as long as you pass the correct parameters, as I wanted to delete the cookie and redirect the user, my code is below:

```
import { deleteCookie } from 'cookies-next';
import { NextResponse, type NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = req.cookies.get("token")?.value!
  const res = NextResponse.next();
  const url = process.env.URL

  const response = await fetch(`${url}/verifyExpToken`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${cookie}`
    }
  })
  const data = await response.json()

  if(data.status == 403){ //token expirado
    deleteCookie('token', { res, req });
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url))
  }else if(data.error){//erros como: token invalido, modificado, ou não assinado
    deleteCookie('token', { res, req });
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/signIn", req.url))
  }
  return res
}
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/home", "/cart", "/contact", "/exploreCourses", "/plains"]
}
```

notice that I passed the res and req as parameters of the deleteCookie function, read more about cookies-next here to know what to pass and when to use it in each case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next.

Comment: This works for protecting routes with cookie?